# Looking for the correct cinoptions for this piece of code

Tags: vim, indentation

What cinoptions can I set for getting the block below indented as shown?

```
f(int *p) 
: a(p)
, b(0)
{
  std::cerr << blah
    << foo << std::endl;
}
```

The closest I've got was to:

```
f(int* p) 
  : a(p)
  , b(0)
  {
    std::cerr << blah
      << foo << std::endl;
  }
```

That's almost what I want, only that everything after `:` is indented :)
For that, I used: `set cino=i0,+2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `i0,+2,t0`? (`tN` is for "a function return type declaration").

That worked for me, but, the vims I tried (7.0 and 7.3) did two different things, neither the same as yours, with `i0,+2`.

Comment: That worked for me too, Andy. Finally using `g0,+2,(2,i0,t0,:0`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you only need one additional option.  I got the results you expected by adding `p0` to the `cinoptions`:

> set cino=i0,+2,p0

This adjusts the K&R style indentation.  [From the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html):

```
pN    Parameter declarations for K&R-style function declarations will
      be indented N characters from the margin.  (default
      'shiftwidth').

    cino=               cino=p0          cino=p2s
      func(a, b)          func(a, b)       func(a, b)
          int a;          int a;                   int a;
          char b;         char b;                  char b;
```

Comment: I get the same output with `set cino=i0,+2` and with `set cino=i0,+2,p0`. May it be that this has to do with some other options? I am using `set cindent`, `set expandtab`, and `filetype indent on`.

Comment: @rturrado: I am not seeing the behavior your report.  When I use your option (without p0) I get an indent on the second two lines, and when I add the p0, it behaves as requested.  Could you do `:mkvimrc`, confirm that the `cinoption` value is correct and then paste the settings you get into a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: I've created a couple of pastebins. First one, with the `:mkvimrc`: http://pastebin.com/FMd3g6F8. Second, with the file indented manually and with `set cino=i0,+2,p0`: http://pastebin.com/iRLQbzuc